# What is the addition in $U\otimes V$ if $U$ and $V$ are vector space?

Tags: tensor-products

Let $U$ a $\mathbb R-$vector space of dimension $m$ and $V$ a $\mathbb R-$vector space of dimension $n$. We define $u\otimes v:=uv^T$ where $u\in U$ and $v\in V$. I have to prove that $$U\otimes V:=\{u\otimes v\mid u\in U,v\in V\}$$
is a vector space of dimension $nm$. My problem is that I even don't know how is defined $u\otimes v+ \tilde u\otimes \tilde v$ where $u,\tilde u\in U$ and $v,\tilde v\in V$. Any idea at this point ? I saw the page on wikipedia, but their construction of $U\otimes V$ is not so intuitive. Their definition is the following one, but I don't see how I can deduce the some of two element in $U\otimes V$.

[image]

Comment: Your definition is wrong. It should rather be $$U\otimes V=\text{Span}\{u\otimes v\mid u\in U, v\in V\},$$ because $\{u\otimes v\mid u\in U,v\in V\}$ is even not a vector space (as you mentioned, the addition is not stable).

Comment: @freakish- Programmers often like to treat vectors as a special case of matrices, where one of the dimensions is equal to $1$. It confuses mathematicians (like me), and they frequently neglect to mention whether they are $1 \times n$ or $n \times 1$. You have to figure it out based on whether they talk about $uv^T$ as the dot product or a tensor product.

Answer (score 1):

The tensor product is by definition bilinear, that is, it follows the rules that $u_1\otimes v+u_2\otimes v=(u_1+u_2)\otimes v$ and $u\otimes v_1+u\otimes v_2=u\otimes(v_1+v_2)$, as well as $\lambda(u\otimes v)=(\lambda u)\otimes v=u\otimes(\lambda v)$.

To properly use this to calculate the sum of arbitrary tensor products, you need to choose bases of $U$ and $V$ and decompose $u,\tilde u,v,\tilde v$. For an easy example, let $U,V$ be two-dimensional with bases $\{b_1,b_2\}\subset U,~\{c_1,c_2\}\subset V$. Then we have

$$\begin{align}
u\otimes v+\tilde u\otimes\tilde v&=(u_1b_1+u_2b_2)\otimes(v_1c_1+v_2c_2)+(\tilde u_1b_1+\tilde u_2b_2)\otimes(\tilde v_1c_1+\tilde v_2c_2)\\
&=u_1v_1(b_1\otimes c_1)+u_1v_2(b_1\otimes c_2)+u_2v_1(b_2\otimes c_1)+u_2v_2(b_2\otimes c_2)~+\\
&\color{white}{=}\tilde u_1\tilde v_1(b_1\otimes c_1)+\tilde u_1\tilde v_2(b_1\otimes c_2)+\tilde u_2\tilde v_1(b_2\otimes c_1)+\tilde u_2\tilde v_2(b_2\otimes c_2)\\
&=(u_1v_1+\tilde u_1\tilde v_1)(b_1\otimes c_1)+(u_1v_2+\tilde u_1\tilde v_2)(b_1\otimes c_2)\\
&\color{white}{=}+(u_2v_1+\tilde u_2\tilde v_1)(b_2\otimes c_1)+(u_2v_2+\tilde u_2\tilde v_2)(b_2\otimes c_2)
\end{align}$$

For higher dimensions, it is imperative that you do this using some abbreviating notation. It will come out like this:

$$\left(\sum_{i\in I}x_ib_i\right)\otimes\left(\sum_{j\in J}y_j c_j\right)+\left(\sum_{i\in I}z_ib_i\right)\otimes\left(\sum_{j\in J}w_jc_j\right)=\sum_{i\in I\\j\in J}(x_iy_j+z_iw_j)(b_i\otimes c_j).$$

Note that the sums are always finite even if $I,J$ are not, since $(b_i)_I,(c_j)_J$ are bases of $U$ and $V$, so this seemingly infinite sum is still well-defined.